# I want use the pseudo records(new - old) in package

Tags: oracle, plsql, records

I wrote a trigger and I used :old and :new tags for many times. And I want to make package this code block. But old and new reference records  not compiled and declared in package. I received this error code: [Error] PLS-00049 (38: 20): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.column2'. anyone help me?

```
insert into  table

              (
                  column1
                 ,column2
                 ,colum3
              )

    values  (
               :new.column1
              ,:new.column2
              ,:new.column3
            );
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that.  You can pass the values in to the package procedure as parameters of course: `mypkg.proc(p1=>:new.col1, ...);`

Comment: Define a record structure, assign the :new values to that, and pass the record as a single parameter?

Comment: [Correlation Names and Pseudorecords](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955) are only available in trigger body. The documentation addresses also your other questions.

Comment: Guys thanks a lot for your answers. I defined %rowtype and all pseudo-record values asssign the new strings on trigger scope. I called %rowtype and strings on package body. Totaly working.